# Org-mode exporting to pdf for emacs.app on Mac OS X

Tags: pdf, emacs, latex, docbook, org-mode

Org-mode, love it.
I've been trying to set up the mac to export anything to pdf. No easy way yet.
First there's org-export-as-pdf which first exports to pdf then generates a pdf.
I get "pdflatex: command not found", fair enough... stumped.
Other option is org-export-as-docbook-pdf which exports as DocBook XML then pdf.
In this case I get "XSLT processor command is not set correctly".

In both cases the .tex and .xml files are generated.
In both cases I get through enough reading to think: "there must be an easier way", and here I am.
Thanks.

Mac OS X 10.6.7
Emacs.app 23.2.1
Org-mode 7.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the short answer is that you'll need to install either of the missing tools. In my case, I use LaTeX extensively, so I have TeX Live installed. That will give you pdflatex which will let org-export-as-pdf work properly. However, TeX is a huge system (several hundred megabytes to download), so if your only need for it is org-mode, you might rather install a docbook processor.

I'm not an expert on org-mode, so maybe there's a way around it. You could generate HTML and convert that to PDF using the method of your choice, but I'm guessing the optimum path is to install one of the processors needed.

Comment: The TeX Live Basic TeX distribution is only 92M, and should be enough for org-mode's exporting. http://www.tug.org/mactex/morepackages.html

Comment: Almost works: Getting `! LaTeX Error: File 'wrapfig.sty' not found.`

Comment: So the wrapfig.sty error can be ignored.  If I run pdflatex outside of emacs, and just keep hitting enter a PDF can be created

Comment: Here are the steps to make it work: 1. Install BasicTex
2. Install MacTex Additions
3. Run Tex Live Update
4. Install these four packages:
wrapfig
marvosym
wasy
wasysym

Comment: To follow up on @Lionel's comment, once you have BasicTeX installed you can run `tlmgr install <package>` to install `wrapfig`, etc.

Answer (score 6):

I stumbled into this error today after upgrading to OS X Lion recently.

The reason you get the `pdflatex: command not found` error message is because
Emacs is not including the texlive binaries into its PATH, so you have to 
add them manually.

So, after having downloaded and install the most recent version of the Texlive distribution for OS X [from here](http://www.tug.org/mactex/2011/), something like these lines should solve the error:

```
(if (eq window-system 'mac)
   (add-to-list 'exec-path "/usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/universal-darwin")
)
```

Comment: In addition: 1. Install BasicTex
2. Install MacTex Additions
3. Run Tex Live Update
4. Install these four packages:
wrapfig
marvosym
wasy
wasysym

Answer (score 1):

In order to export an org-mode file to pdf (xslt+fo) in osx:

- Install docbook stylesheets, an xslt and a fo processors

$ brew install docbook saxon fop

- Set variables as specified by org-mode documentation, and your processors' documentation:

(require 'org-docbook)
;;
(setq org-export-docbook-xsl-fo-proc-command "/usr/local/bin/fop \"%i\" \"%o\"")
(setq org-export-docbook-xslt-proc-command "/usr/local/bin/saxon -o:\"%o\" -s:\"%i\" -xsl:\"%s\"")
(setq org-export-docbook-xslt-stylesheet "/usr/local/Cellar/docbook/5.0/docbook/xsl-ns/1.77.1/fo/docbook.xsl")

For more up to date information: https://gist.github.com/4534326

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way I've found is to install LibreOffice for Mac and then follow the steps below.

Customize the variable org-export-odt-convert-processes and add an entry

```
Converter Name: LibreOffice
Converter Value: /Applications/LibreOffice.app/Contents/MacOS/soffice --headless --convert-to %f%x --outdir %d %i
```

Customize the variable org-export-odt-convert-process and select "LibreOffice".

Customize the variable org-export-odt-preferred-output-format and select "pdf".

Export your file to OpenDocument format (C-c C-e o) which will now create an Open Document (.odt) file and immediately use the command line converter to create a .pdf file.

Answer (score 0):

You can export DocBook XML and then format it to PDF. For DocBook to PDF formatting you will need to install XSLFO processor and DocBook XSL stylesheets ([as described in the org-mode manual](http://orgmode.org/org.html#DocBook-export-commands)). Additionally you can use [docbookpublishing.com](http://docbookpublishing.com) web service for DocBook to PDF formatting.